# How can I remove unnecessary square brackets Python

Tags: python

For example, I'm having this:
a = [['1'], ['2'], ['3']]

How can I change it into:
a = ['1', '2', '3']

Thanks!

Comment: `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a))`

Comment: `a = np.array(a).squeeze()` or `[l[0] for l in a]`

Comment: @SilverSlash, there is no `numpy` tag ;)

Comment: You have a list of lists, and it appears that you want a list. But the square brackets aren't really unnecessary, because that is how you represent a list of lists. So your question is really "How do I flatten a list of lists into a single list containing the elements of all the sublists?" And as you can see from the comments and answers, there are a lot of ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

ooh, i'll play.

```
a = [i[0] for i in a]
```

(assuming you only have one item in each sublist)

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
a = [['1'], ['2'], ['3']]
lst = []
for subLst in a:
    lst.extend(subLst)
print(lst)
```

But in most cases this means that the generation of the list `a` get improved ...